# Composer - "but these are rejected by your constraint."

Tags: php, composer-php

I have this "partial" composer.json file:

```json
{
    ...
    "repositories": {
        ...
        "civicrm-core": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core.git"
        },
        "civicrm-drupal-8": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8.git"
        },
        ...
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "civicrm/civicrm-core": "dev-roundearth-5.24.6 as 5.24.6",
        "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "dev-roundearth-5.24.0 as dev-master",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        ...
    }
    ...
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    ...
}
```

Doing `composer update civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 civicrm/civicrm-core`, I get this output:

> Problem 1
> - The requested package civicrm/civicrm-core dev-roundearth-5.24.6 as 5.24.6@dev exists as civicrm/civicrm-core[4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.6.10, 4.6.11, 4.6.12, 4.6.13, 4.6.14, 4.6.15, 4.6.16, 4.6.17, 4.6.18, 4.6.19, 4.6.2, 4.6.20, 4.6.21, 4.6.22, 4.6.23, 4.6.24, 4.6.25, 4.6.26, 4.6.27, 4.6.28, 4.6.29, 4.6.3, 4.6.30, 4.6.31, 4.6.32, 4.6.33, 4.6.34, 4.6.35, 4.6.36, 4.6.37, 4.6.38, 4.6.4, 4.6.5, 4.6.6, 4.6.7, 4.6.8, 4.6.9, 4.6.alpha1, 4.6.alpha2, 4.6.alpha3, 4.6.alpha4, 4.6.alpha5, 4.6.alpha6, 4.6.alpha7, 4.6.beta1, 4.6.beta2, 4.6.beta3, 4.6.beta4, 4.6.beta5, 4.6.x-dev, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.7.10, 4.7.11, 4.7.12, 4.7.13, 4.7.14, 4.7.15, 4.7.16, 4.7.17, 4.7.18, 4.7.19, 4.7.2, 4.7.20, 4.7.21, 4.7.22, 4.7.23, 4.7.24, 4.7.25, 4.7.26, 4.7.27, 4.7.28, 4.7.29, 4.7.3, 4.7.30, 4.7.31, 4.7.4, 4.7.5, 4.7.6, 4.7.7, 4.7.8, 4.7.9, 4.7.alpha1, 4.7.alpha2, 4.7.alpha3, 4.7.alpha4, 4.7.alpha5, 4.7.beta1, 4.7.beta2, 4.7.beta3, 4.7.beta4, 4.7.beta5, 4.7.beta6, 4.7.beta7, 4.7.beta8, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.x-dev, 5.10.0, 5.10.1, 5.10.2, 5.10.3, 5.10.4, 5.10.x-dev, 5.11.0, 5.11.x-dev, 5.12.0, 5.12.1, 5.12.2, 5.12.3, 5.12.4, 5.12.x-dev, 5.13.0, 5.13.1, 5.13.2, 5.13.3, 5.13.4, 5.13.5, 5.13.x-dev, 5.14.0, 5.14.1, 5.14.2, 5.14.x-dev, 5.15.0, 5.15.1, 5.15.2, 5.15.x-dev, 5.16.0, 5.16.1, 5.16.2, 5.16.3, 5.16.4, 5.16.x-dev, 5.17.0, 5.17.1, 5.17.2, 5.17.3, 5.17.4, 5.17.5, 5.17.x-dev, 5.18.0, 5.18.1, 5.18.2, 5.18.3, 5.18.4, 5.18.x-dev, 5.19.0, 5.19.1, 5.19.2, 5.19.3, 5.19.4, 5.19.x-dev, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.2.x-dev, 5.20.0, 5.20.1, 5.20.2, 5.20.3, 5.20.x-dev, 5.21.0, 5.21.1, 5.21.2, 5.21.x-dev, 5.22.0, 5.22.1, 5.22.x-dev, 5.23.0, 5.23.1, 5.23.2, 5.23.3, 5.23.4, 5.23.x-dev, 5.24.0, 5.24.1, 5.24.2, 5.24.3, 5.24.4, 5.24.5, 5.24.6, 5.24.x-dev, 5.25.0, 5.25.x-dev, 5.26.0, 5.26.1, 5.26.2, 5.26.x-dev, 5.27.0, 5.27.1, 5.27.2, 5.27.3, 5.27.4, 5.27.x-dev, 5.28.0, 5.28.1, 5.28.2, 5.28.3, 5.28.4, 5.28.x-dev, 5.29.0, 5.29.1, 5.29.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.x-dev, 5.30.0, 5.30.1, 5.30.x-dev, 5.31.0, 5.31.x-dev, 5.32.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.0, 5.8.1, 5.8.2, 5.8.x-dev, 5.9.0, 5.9.1, 5.9.x-dev, dev-4.7.10-rc, dev-4.7.11-rc, dev-4.7.12-rc, dev-4.7.13-rc, dev-4.7.14-rc, dev-4.7.15-rc, dev-4.7.16-rc, dev-4.7.17-rc, dev-4.7.18-rc, dev-4.7.19-rc, dev-4.7.20-rc, dev-4.7.21-rc, dev-4.7.22-rc, dev-4.7.23-rc, dev-4.7.24-rc, dev-4.7.25-rc, dev-4.7.26-rc, dev-4.7.27-rc, dev-4.7.28-rc, dev-4.7.29-rc, dev-4.7.30-rc, dev-4.7.31-rc, dev-4.7.7-rc, dev-4.7.8-rc, dev-4.7.9-rc, dev-CRM-19755=1, dev-GL316-cache_key_no_whitespace, dev-JoeMurray-patch-2, dev-add-license-1, dev-doctrine, dev-master, dev-master-doctrine, dev-revert-10998-CRM-21197, dev-revert-9899-CRM-20179] but these are rejected by your constraint.

> Problem 2
> - The requested package civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 dev-roundearth-5.24.0 as dev-master@dev exists as civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.x-dev, 5.10.0, 5.10.1, 5.10.2, 5.10.3, 5.10.4, 5.10.x-dev, 5.11.0, 5.11.x-dev, 5.12.0, 5.12.1, 5.12.2, 5.12.3, 5.12.4, 5.12.x-dev, 5.13.0, 5.13.1, 5.13.2, 5.13.3, 5.13.4, 5.13.5, 5.13.x-dev, 5.14.0, 5.14.1, 5.14.2, 5.14.x-dev, 5.15.0, 5.15.1, 5.15.2, 5.15.x-dev, 5.16.0, 5.16.1, 5.16.2, 5.16.3, 5.16.4, 5.16.x-dev, 5.17.0, 5.17.1, 5.17.2, 5.17.3, 5.17.4, 5.17.5, 5.17.x-dev, 5.18.0, 5.18.1, 5.18.2, 5.18.3, 5.18.4, 5.18.x-dev, 5.19.0, 5.19.1, 5.19.2, 5.19.3, 5.19.4, 5.19.x-dev, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.2.x-dev, 5.20.0, 5.20.1, 5.20.2, 5.20.3, 5.20.x-dev, 5.21.0, 5.21.1, 5.21.2, 5.21.x-dev, 5.22.0, 5.22.1, 5.22.x-dev, 5.23.0, 5.23.1, 5.23.2, 5.23.3, 5.23.4, 5.23.x-dev, 5.24.0, 5.24.1, 5.24.2, 5.24.3, 5.24.4, 5.24.5, 5.24.6, 5.24.x-dev, 5.25.0, 5.25.x-dev, 5.26.0, 5.26.1, 5.26.2, 5.26.x-dev, 5.27.0, 5.27.1, 5.27.2, 5.27.3, 5.27.4, 5.27.x-dev, 5.28.0, 5.28.1, 5.28.2, 5.28.3, 5.28.4, 5.28.x-dev, 5.29.0, 5.29.1, 5.29.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.x-dev, 5.30.0, 5.30.1, 5.30.x-dev, 5.31.0, 5.31.x-dev, 5.32.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.2, 5.7.3, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.0, 5.8.1, 5.8.2, 5.8.x-dev, 5.9.0, 5.9.1, 5.9.x-dev, dev-master, dev-resourceOrder] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Shouldn't it work just fine? I have this composer version: `1.10.1 2020-03-13 20:34:27`

I don't get why it's being rejected. I think I found a few issue where it says I need to add `@dev` although my minimum-stability is already set to "dev". I also tried adding @dev in them but the error persists.

I also did `why-not` and got the following:

```
$ composer why-not civicrm/civicrm-core dev-roundearth-5.24.6

civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8  5.27.4       requires  civicrm/civicrm-core (>=5.21.0)
drupal/civicrm_entity     dev-8.x-3.x  requires  civicrm/civicrm-core (~5.0)
roundearth/roundearth     dev-8.x-1.x  requires  civicrm/civicrm-core (^5.3.1)

$ composer why-not civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 dev-roundearth-5.24.0

drupal/civicrm_entity  dev-8.x-3.x  requires  civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 (~5.0|dev-master)
roundearth/roundearth  dev-8.x-1.x  requires  civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 (dev-master)
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you're asking for a `dev-roundearth-5.24.6` and `dev-roundearth-5.24.0` versions which are not listed as potential packages.

If you replace `dev-roundearth-5.24.6 as 5.24.6` and `dev-roundearth-5.24.0 as dev-master` by another listed version like `5.24.6` in your `composer.json` and save the file, it should work again.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the alias here would just work. `dev-roundearth-5.24.6` is required by another package.